# How to make PhpStorm to change font in debug console?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

How can I change this font? I cannot find it in settings

[image]

Comment: In general, console font is changed via "Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font" settings menu window. Does it work for you?

Comment: No, it changes font in other console windows, but not this debug console window :(

Comment: I had to turn off the webconsole - in PhpStorm's registry unchecked "js.debugger.webconsole". It's not that fancy, but readability was improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger console does use the font settings specified in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font**. But font rendering differs from other consoles because the debugger uses JavaFX for the UI while all other parts of IDE use different technologies.
We are now working on improving the font rendering for JavaFX components. Related ticket: [WEB-38444](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38444)